# Bootstrap Body Overflow - Using overflow-x creates mobile scrolling issues

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap, mobile, overflow, mobile-safari

I've more or less finished a simple bootstrap site for a client, however I ran into an issue where the body element seems to have an extra 160px on the right side! I've spent like 3 hours already trying to find an answer.

To partially solve this problem I added the below css to the head:

`html, body { overflow-x: hidden;}`

This got rid of the extra 160px however on mobile devices (only tested iOS) the scrolling action is now incredibly sticky - rather than the fluid scroll we expect on a mobile device. Instead of one fast flick of the finger making the page continue scrolling, now when the finger leaves the screen the page stops dead.

In terms of user experience this isn't really acceptable and has been a real pain to try and solve.

I've put the site here for you to try on a mobile to feel the 'stickyness' [goo.gl/yEI3rn](http://goo.gl/yEI3rn)

On desktop you can use inspector to disable the overflow-x:hidden; on the body to see the extra pixels on the right.

If anyone can investigate the site and tell me any one of the following it would be very useful:

1. Which element in the body is causing the body to have the extra width?
2. Why the body element has the excess width?
3. Is there an alternative to overflow-x that will not create mobile scrolling issues?
4. Any other areas to investigate to try and solve this issue?

Thanks so much for any insight here!

Answer (score 0):

you can try adding this to your css to see which element goes all the way:

```
 * {
   outline: 1px solid right;
 }
```